Why didn't 54th MA use swords in their assault on Fort Wagner?
In the movie Glory (1989) the 54th Massachusetts regiment fails their assault on Fort Wagner at the end of the movie because they are filed through a chokepoint and shot to death. Besides attacking at Dusk instead of at night, why didn't the colored troops in that engagement and in general when attacking forts do not use swords or axes rather than exclusively muskets which have RPM of 3. We can see how the Zulu for example at Isandlwana were able to beat up technologically superior British who had faster shooting Martini-Henries than the Union muskets and had been fighting in the daylight with simple spears and cow-hide shields. And later yet in WW1 when German Stosstruppen or Italian Arditi using knives and trench sticks/maces to assault enemy trenches, where the rifles were especially more fast firing.

Were the soldiers of the 54th issued swords and axes? It's very difficult to use equipment that you don't have. I'd imagine that their muskets had bayonets for CQB.

Is Glory a historically accurate portrayal of the assault?

yeah im asking why didnt troops assaulting forts be issued with swords instead of long bayonets at the end of long muskets that were probably unwieldy in CQB. Glory is factual when it comes to not using swords. I dont understand what makes the essense of my question so difficult to grasp vs. "why didn't samurai use shields" like cmon, its not that deep lmao

"Why didn't militia in the 1850s use infiltration tactics developed in WWI for elite units" is an interesting question to consider

@max "...vs. 'why didn't samurai use shields'" -- They did.

I think you would find carrying the combination of a long gun (rifle, musket) and a sword/axe prohibitively impractical in a combat situation.  One or the other, but not both.  Now, if you opt for swords and you end up in a longer range engagement, which can happen in many cases, you will also get cut to pieces.  I also believe that the WW1 infiltration troops operated with knives, handguns and grenades.  Not knives and rifles.

"Train as you fight, fight as you train"  Probably not terribly practical for the 54th Mass to be the only infantry regiment in the entire Union army trained to fight with only swords and axes

I leave the "they didn't have any" to @OldPadawan, and just add a couple more arguments.

A musket with a bayonet is, effectively, a spear that can double as a club. A spear is an effective close-quarters weapon, especially if you can maintain some kind of formation. A sword has only marginal advantages in this situation, if at all.

Fighting effectively with any weapon takes training. The men of the 54th didn't train with swords. They did train with the bayonet.

To use swords effectively, they would have to drop their muskets (or sling them over their back, which would be cumbersome). Soldiers are not keen on leaving their primary weapons behind.


As for your WWI example, trench warfare was space restricted, giving shorter weapons an advantage. The Germans actually kept making their bayonets shorter over time due to this (Seitengewehr 98 was 20 inch, the 98/05 was 15 inch, and the 84/98 was 10 inch).


The Dragoons, and later the Cavalry continued to carry the 1840 Dragoon Saber up to the start of the Civil War. In 1857 the Army authorized a Light Cavalry Saber, and began production in 1859 (this is sometimes referred to as the Model 1860).
While most Cavalry units received the new saber, once the war started virtually all of the 1840 pattern sabers on hand were issued as well. Mounted members of Light Artillery Batteries dutifully were issued sabers as well, specifically the Model 1840 Light Artillery Saber.
Despite images of the dramatic cavalry charge with lifted sabers gleaming in the sun, less that one percent of all the casualties in the Civil War were inflicted by an edged weapon of any type, saber or bayonet. Survey of U.S. Army Uniforms, Weapons and Accoutrements - pages 23-28

Not only were only dragoons and cavalry provided with sabers, but there's no mention anywhere (that I remember or could find trace of) of knives or any other edge weapon.
So, to answer your question, soldiers can't use weapons they don't have. This is just based on facts, and doesn't take into account the possible debatable depiction of the attack in the movie you mention (as I haven't seen it).
There are some other related (interesting) readings:

The Uniform, Arms, And Equipment of the Union Soldier,
1861-1865 - pages 25 to 46
11 Objects Carried by American Civil War Soldiers


A standard infantry regiment in the US Civil war had 10 companies and a total of 30 company officers and three field officers, plus an adjutant, I think, for a total of about 34.
Officers would be issued officer's swords.
A standard infantry regiment would have two musicians - drummers or fifers - per company, and thus 20 musicians plus a drum major.  Musicians were issued short musician's swords.
Thus a more or less standard federal infantry regiment would have about a thousand men in total (always fewer by the time they got to a battle) and about 55 at most would be issued with swords.
And I don't know what proportion of infantry assaults would involve the musicians charging with the men.  After all, some of the musicians were young boys.
The memoirs of one Civil War drummer boy say that the drummers in his regiment considered their swords useless impediments.  One night in camp they tossed their swords in their scabbards up into a tree and left them dangling from their straps. Musicians were not issued guns.  So if the musicians in that regiment expected to charge, they probably would have kept their swords.
So that would leave a full regiment with only about 33 men equipped with swords.
Soldiers with the assignment of pioneers had axes and shovels to clear the path.  Pioneers also worked as engineers constructing field fortifications.
I doubt whether the typical Union regiment had many pioneers with axes.
